# Winston Logger (v2.4) writing to file even after rotation

Tags: node.js, winston

I have a transport for console out as well as one for file out. 
This works fine and creates a new log file, while renaming the old one 
eg. logs/appLogs.txt and logs/appLogs1.txt

The issue i face is that it continues to write to the first file even though its **above** the maxsize. Winston is logging to **both** files, but splitting the logs between the two.

eg: appLogs1.txt
`2019-02-21T18:53:04.581Z - debug: ... logs`

and appLogs.txt
`2019-02-21T18:53:04.538Z - debug: ... logs`

I can ssh into the container and with `ls -l` see both files grow.

below is my winston config:

```js
new winston.Logger({
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.Console({
                    colorize: true,
                    timestamp: true,
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    stderrLevels: ['error'],
                    humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
                    level: level,
                    label: category
                }),
                new winston.transports.File({
                    filename: 'logs/appLogs.txt',
                    maxsize: 5000000,
                    maxFiles: 20,
                    tailable : true,
                    timestamp: true,
                    handleExceptions: true,
                    humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
                    level: level,
                    label: category,
                    json: false
                })
            ]
        })
```

appLogs1.txt is now 9948153 bytes, and appLogs.txt is 882922